# Ideals of $C^0([0, 1]; \Bbb R)$ and compactness

Tags: abstract-algebra, continuity, compactness, ideals

Let $C := C^0([0, 1]; \Bbb R)$ the ring of continuous real functions on $[0, 1]$. Let $I \subset C$ an ideal. We suppose that $I$ is not contained in any $I_x:= \{f \in C \lvert f(x) = 0\}$. Show that $I=C$. Hint :  the Heine–Borel theorem might be useful.

What I started doing is the following : since $I$ is not contained in any $I_x$ then $I \neq (0)$ and let $f$ be a non-zero function. If $f$ is constant then $f\equiv c\in \Bbb R$ and $c^{-1}f\equiv 1 \implies I = C$. And if not, I had a few ideas that led to nothing too helpful : $\forall x \in [0,1]$ I can always find a function in $f_x \in I$ that is in $I_x$. I struggle to see where Heine-Borel can be used here.

Answer (score 1):

Over-arching idea: find an $f \in I$ so that $f^{-1}\{0\} = \emptyset$. Then IVT implies that $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \in [0, 1]$ or $f(x) < 0$ for all $x \in [0, 1]$ (and, multiplying by $-1$, we might as well assume the former). Such a function has to have a positive minimum, by the extreme value theorem, so $\frac{1}{f} \in C$, making $f$ a unit, and so $I = C$. It's like your non-zero constant function idea, but more general!

Now, it's not immediately obvious that such an $f$ must exist. Sure, there is no $x \in [0, 1]$ so that $f(x) = 0$ for all $f \in I$, but if we allow the $x$ to vary with $f$, i.e. for all $f \in I$ there exists some $x \in [0, 1]$ such that $f(x) = 0$, then this could well be true. This is where we need the compactness of $[0, 1]$.

In particular, we can use the Finite Intersection Principle (FIP). That is, if we have a family of closed subsets of $[0, 1]$ with the property that any finite subfamily has non-empty intersection, then the enttire family has a common point of intersection.

The family we will be considering is $\{f^{-1}\{0\} : f \in I\}$. Note that continuity implies immediately that these sets are closed! This family cannot have a common point of intersection $x$, because this would imply $I \subseteq I_x$, against assumption, so there must be some $f_1, \ldots, f_n$ so that
$$f_1^{-1}\{0\} \cap \ldots \cap f_n^{-1}\{0\} = \emptyset.$$
Let
$$f = f_1^2 + f_2^2 + \ldots + f_n^2.$$
First note that $f_i^2 = f_i \cdot f_i \in I$, and so $f \in I$. I claim that $f^{-1}\{0\} = \emptyset$, as required. Note that,
\begin{align*}
f(x) = 0 &\implies f_1(x)^2 + \ldots + f_n(x)^2 = 0 \\
&\implies f_1(x) = f_2(x) = \ldots = f_n(x) = 0 \\
&\implies x \in f_1^{-1}\{0\} \cap \ldots \cap f_n^{-1}\{0\} = \emptyset,
\end{align*}
a contradiction. Thus, $f^{-1}\{0\} = \emptyset$ as required, and so $f$ is a unit, and $I = C$.

Comment: I am not sure to agree with the sentence "for all $f \in I$ there exists some $x \in [0,1]$ such that $f(x)=0$." but the rest seems fine